# Availability of new apt syntax

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

I've noticed on Ubuntu >= 14.04, it is possible to use such syntax as `apt install mypackage`, no longer requiring use of the traditional set of `apt` tools like `apt-get` and `apt-cache`.

Not only is the command shorter (and contained in one keyword instead of remembering all of them), the display in the terminal is also "better." The `apt install` and `apt search` syntax has colors turned on by default, and installation/upgrade sequences have a colored total progress bar at the bottom.

I prefer this new behavior, but I have no idea where this new syntax is from. The word I get from my friends who use Debian is that it's probably just an Ubuntu thing. Is this true?

How can I achieve this new method on Debian? Is it just a newer update of `apt`, or is this Canonical mischief?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your friends who use Debian haven't seen it is probably because they're using an older version.  *I'm* using an older version (on Wheezy.) I downloaded the source from the Debian package page for Jessie (testing) and the changelog makes it look like the new features are there.
Edit:  I just installed Jessie to a VM.  The man page matches the man page on the current Mint/Ubuntu installations:

[image: Man page for apt from jessie]

Comment: I figured as much. Would someone mind confirming this?